# How do I show an Iframe in a in a visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, rerender, iframe

I am trying to show an Iframe in an visualforce page but this does not seem to render the page. I have read that this could be a certificate issue.

If so is there any other way to render the Iframe for example with javascript.

Visualforce

```
<apex:page >
    Hello
    <apex:iframe src="https://www.mollie.com/paymentscreen/testmode/?method=ideal&token=arwe7v" scrolling="true" id="theIframe"/>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for including the specific site; it actually made it really easy to see what's going on. The headers for this site contain the key-value: "X-FRAME-OPTIONS: Deny". As such, you cannot embed this site in an iframe. This is a conscious decision made by the provider. You will need to engage with them to determine if there is an alternative solution. Any attempt to embed the site, including JavaScript, will fail as long as this header is presented to the client. As the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) puts it:

> `deny`
>
> The page cannot be displayed in a frame, regardless of the site attempting to do so.